# Why can't I use Nuget to recognize the Swashbuckle.AspNetCore package

Tags: asp.net-core, swagger

My project needs to use import swagger, for this, I study the documentation. But referring to the Nuget package according to the first step, I found that the Swashbuckle.AspNetCore package could not be recognized. Prompt error:

```
Nuget is neither responsible nor licensed for third-party packages.
```

Comment: this is not an error... please study more and provide some more information that would allow us to help you. Specifically, what makes you thing that the Swashbuckle.AspNetCore package could not be recognized?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your Nuget download interface to see if the source of the package is checked, like this:

[image]

[image]

Check it to download normally, you can try it.

Refer to this article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/nuget-org/nuget-org-faq